# Setting default exception handlers in a base class - good or bad

Tags: php, design-patterns, exception

So, I have a simple base class for Server - and I realised that for a number of Exceptions that I'm throwing, the handling would be fairly consistent for all Server types (for example, HTTP 4xx errors).

So I've setup a callback and default handler like so:

Server class:

```
<?php

abstract class Server
{
    protected $methodsAllowed = array('POST', 'GET');
    protected $requiredParameters = array();

    protected function isMethodAllowed()
    {
        if (!isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])) {
            $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] = 'CLI';
        }

        if (!in_array($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'], $this->methodsAllowed)) {
            throw new Exception_Server_MethodNotAllowed($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'], $this->methodsAllowed);
        }
    }

    protected function areParametersCorrect()
    {
        foreach ($this->requiredParameters as $parameter) {
            if (!in_array($parameter, array_keys($_REQUEST))) {
                throw new Exception_Server_MissingParameter('Missing parameter "' . $parameter . '" in request');
            }
        }
    }

    protected function init()
    {
        $this->isMethodAllowed();
        $this->areParametersCorrect();
    }

    protected function sendXML($xml)
    {
        header('Content-Type: text/xml');
        echo $xml;
        exit;
    }

    abstract public function respond();

    public static function exceptionHandler($exception)
    {
        switch (true) {
            case $exception instanceof Exception_HTTP_400:
                error_log($exception->getMessage());
                header('HTTP/1.1 400 Not Found');
                exit;

            case $exception instanceof Exception_HTTP_404:
                error_log($exception->getMessage());
                header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
                exit;

            case $exception instanceof Exception_HTTP_405:
                error_log($exception->getMessage());
                header('HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed');
                header('Allow: ' . implode(', ', $exception->getMethodsAllowed()));
                exit;
        }
    }
}

Exception_Handler::register('Server_Factory::exceptionHandler');

class Exception_Server_MethodNotAllowed extends Exception_HTTP_405 { }
class Exception_Server_MissingParameter extends Exception_HTTP_400 { }
```

Default handler:

```
class Exception_Handler
{
    protected static $callbacks = array();

    public static function register($callback)
    {
        if (!in_array($callback, self::$callbacks)) {
            self::$callbacks[] = $callback;
        }
    }

    public static function handle($exception)
    {
        foreach (self::$callbacks as $callback) {
            call_user_func($callback, $exception);
        }
    }
}

set_exception_handler('Exception_Handler::handle');
```

Now - any application that uses this base class can override the default exception handling by catching the Exceptions, but it also allows for a default handling.

Is this a good design decision?

The pro's as I see it is - it allows for a base behaviour, and allows keeps the Server exceptions group with the Server code, and ???

The con's are - it is using callbacks (and I'm finding PHPUnit is not reporting coverage of the callbacks), and ???

NB - I may not be using the best methods to determine the nature of the Exception - `instanceof` 'felt' about right, but if there's better, I'd like to know...

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen this kind of using exceptions for web request handling anywhere else. The idea seem good but keep in mind that you can only define the handling once per application. There will be cases where you want to handle a Exception_Server_MethodNotAllowed as Exception_HTTP_405 in once part of your application and as Exception_HTTP_400 in another part of your application. You could catch this exceptions somewhere in between your exception handler and your actual throw and than try to re-define the exception but things will get messy real quick.

In my applications I do handle the errors right away. As soon as something unexpected happens I tell to either do a 404 or a 500. For everything in between there will be a 500 and a error log. If the error is something to worry about, I change the handling where it occurs.

Comment: So, you only use 404 or 500? There are a whole range of other statuses and messages for the client to react to, and as web developers we should be using the full range as applicable...

Comment: Also, as I noted in my question - the handler method in the base class is only called as part of the default handler - that is, when the exceptions are not caught anywhere else. The application can easily override this default behaviour with a try{} catch{} placed wherever, and catching the appropriate exception...

Comment: @HorusKol I basically use only 301, 307, 404 and 500 as those seem to be accepted widely by all browsers and all bots (google bot, ...). The bigger your project gets the harder error and exception handling will get. You should keep it as simple as you can. Just my two cents :-)

Comment: Well - my question isn't about HTTP headers - but rather about exceptions and handling. However, you probably should think about also using 400, 401, 403, 405 and 410 as appropriate... I think you'd be surprised at what browsers and bots will actually acknowledge.

Comment: @HorusKol I would use those if I ever need to :-) Your question is if it is considered good or bad to set the default handling in the base class. So my answer is more no than yes :-)